# Mysql INSERT INTO from another table with condition and limit

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that have a one-to-many relationship table1 (one), table2 (many).

```
table1 has (t1_id) as KEY
table2 has (t2_id) as KEY and t2_t1_id as as refference to table1
```

Now in `table1` I need a column (`rand_t2_id`) that holds an `id` from `table2`, I do not really care which one

This is the query I tried

```
INSERT INTO table1 (rand_t2_id)
SELECT t2_id
FROM table2
WHERE table1.t1_id = table2.t2_t1_id;
```

There also needs to be a limit build in somewhere if that is needed. I only need one id from table2

No luck here tho, anyone know a fix?

Comment: What do you mean you don't care which t2_id is referenced from each rand_t2_id?

Comment: Sorry if you guys didn't understand. I'm glad some people did tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO you could try

```
UPDATE table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.t1_id = t2.t2_t1_id;
SET t1.rand_t2_id = t2.t2_id
```

I assume you already have a column named `rand_t2_id` on your `table1`.

Comment: Worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (t2_t1_id, rand_t2_id)
SELECT t2_id
FROM (  SELECT t2_id, t2_t1_id
        FROM table2
        ORDER BY RAND()) AS h
GROUP BY t2_t1_id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rand_t2_id = VALUES(rand_t2_id)
```

I suppose that's what you're after?

This query would insert a random t2_id into relevant table1.